# How to clean gaps between cells in generated excel file using apache poi

Tags: java, eclipse, excel, apache-poi

I'm using apache poi to generate an excel file document, i'am importing data from database, and i use two queries for that, but when i'am filling cells, but i have a gap between results of the two queries like in the picture below

[image]

and normaly it should be like this (pic2)

[image]

here is the code i used for that

```
public static void Excel () {


        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet sheet1 = workbook.createSheet("Etat");

//***************HEADER


           Cell cell1 = sheet1.createRow(2).createCell(1);
           cell1.setCellValue("NUMEROS");
           sheet1.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(2,2,1,4));
                 //  new Region(2,(short)1,2,(short)4));

           XSSFCellStyle CellST = workbook.createCellStyle();
           XSSFCellStyle CellST2 = workbook.createCellStyle();

           XSSFFont fonte = workbook.createFont();
           fonte.setBoldweight(HSSFFont.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
           fonte.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 7);
           fonte.setFontName("Courier New");


           CellST.setAlignment(HSSFCellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
           CellST.setFont(fonte);
           CellST.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.YELLOW.getIndex());
           CellST.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
           CellST.setBottomBorderColor(Red);

           cell1.setCellStyle(CellST);

           Cell cell2 = sheet1.createRow(3).createCell(1);
           cell2.setCellValue("D'Or-");
           cell2.setCellStyle(CellST);

           Cell cell3 = sheet1.createRow(4).createCell(1);
           cell3.setCellValue("dre");
           cell3.setCellStyle(CellST);

           Cell cell4 = sheet1.getRow(3).createCell(2);
           cell4.setCellValue("des");
           cell4.setCellStyle(CellST);

           Cell cell5 = sheet1.getRow(4).createCell(2);
           cell5.setCellValue("requisitions");
           cell5.setCellStyle(CellST);

...
...
...

//*****************QUERIES & REPORT GENERATION
try {


     String sql1 = "select  ordre.num_ordre , parcelle.code_parcelle, parcelle.num_req , prop_dite.lbl_fr, "
        + "prop_dite.lbl_ar , parcelle.surface_adop , mappe.mappe,"
        + "(select array_to_string(array_agg(consistance.lib_consistance), '+'::text)"
        + "from consistance where id_consistance in (select id_consistance from "
        + "consist_parcelle where id_parcelle = parcelle.id_parcelle)) AS consistance "
        + "from ordre , parcelle , prop_dite , mappe ,mappe_parcelle where "
        + "ordre.id_parcelle = parcelle.id_parcelle and prop_dite.id_prop = "
        + "parcelle.id_prop and mappe_parcelle.id_parcelle= parcelle.id_parcelle and "
        + "mappe_parcelle.id_mappe= mappe.id_mappe and mappe_parcelle.priorite=0";          


     String sql2 = "select  ordre.ordre_ser,( ordre.id_personne, ordre.cts, ordre.htiers ) ,"
                + "CASE when ordre.htiers = 1 then 'Heritiers de '::text else ''::text END || "
                + "(personne.nom_pers::text || ' '::text) || personne.prenom_pers::text"
                + "|| case when ordre.cts = 1 then ' et CTS'::text else ''::text END "
                + "AS lbl, adresse.lib_adresse , adresse.lib_adresse_ar from personne  "
                + ", ordre  , adresse where adresse.id_adresse = personne.id_adresse "
                + "and personne.id_personne = ordre.id_personne order by ordre.ordre_ser ; ";


            Connection conn = conectar();  
            Statement st = conn.createStatement();
             ResultSet rs1 = st.executeQuery(sql1);


             int i =5;
            while (rs1.next())
             {


               Cell cell25 = sheet1.createRow(i).createCell(1);
               cell25.setCellValue(rs1.getString("num_ordre"));
               cell25.setCellStyle(CellST);
               Cell cell26 = sheet1.getRow(i).createCell(4);
               cell26.setCellValue(rs1.getString("code_parcelle"));
               cell26.setCellStyle(CellST);
               Cell cell27 = sheet1.getRow(i).createCell(4);
               cell27.setCellValue(rs1.getString("code_parcelle"));
               cell27.setCellStyle(CellST);

               int rowcount = rs1.getRow();



               Cell cell31 = sheet1.getRow(i).createCell(9);
                 cell31.setCellValue(rs1.getString("lbl_fr"));
                cell31.setCellStyle(CellST);

                   Cell cell32 = sheet1.getRow(i).createCell(10);
                 cell32.setCellValue(rs1.getString("lbl_ar"));
                cell32.setCellStyle(CellST);

                   Cell cell33 = sheet1.getRow(i).createCell(11);
                 cell33.setCellValue(rs1.getString("surface_adop"));
                cell33.setCellStyle(CellST);

                   Cell cell34 = sheet1.getRow(i).createCell(12);
                 cell34.setCellValue(rs1.getString("mappe"));
                cell34.setCellStyle(CellST);

                   Cell cell35 = sheet1.getRow(i).createCell(13);
                 cell35.setCellValue(rs1.getString("consistance"));
                cell35.setCellStyle(CellST);
                i++;    
             }



            rs1.close();
             st.close();

                Statement st2 = conn.createStatement();
                 ResultSet rs2 = st2.executeQuery(sql2);

                int j =5;
                while (rs2.next())
                 {




                       Cell cell28 = sheet1.createRow(5).createCell(5);
                     cell28.setCellValue(rs2.getString("lbl"));
                    cell28.setCellStyle(CellST);
                    Cell cell29 = sheet1.getRow(j).createCell(7);
                    cell29.setCellValue(rs2.getString("lib_adresse"));
                    cell29.setCellStyle(CellST);
                    Cell cell30 = sheet1.getRow(j).createCell(8);
                    cell30.setCellValue(rs2.getString("lib_adresse_ar"));
                    cell30.setCellStyle(CellST);


                       int rowcount2 = rs2.getRow();

                       j++;
                 }

                 rs2.close();
                 st2.close();

            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            String date = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Saadia\\Etatxxx"+date+".xlsx");  
            workbook.write(fileOut);
            fileOut.close();
            System.out.println("Your excel file has been generated!");

}

catch (Exception e ) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

}
```

I think the problem cames from cell's number and the while loop, i made many changes but they didn't work, hope to help to fix the issue of this.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that problem is with line:

```
Cell cell28 = sheet1.createRow(5).createCell(5);
```

You are creating new rows in second loop and that moves down rows that was created previously. Use `getRow()` instead. And perhaps you should use index `j` instead of hardcoded `5`:

```
Cell cell28 = sheet1.getRow(j).createCell(5);
```